# how to create area highchart for large amount of data based date?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, highcharts, react-highcharts

I am creating highchart in react in which I have thousand of data. I have to map that data based on date and completion status(on that particular date how many status got completed).I am not able to create area chart for that and how to map whole data(total 522) in highchart for different dates. Please suggest any help would be highly appreciated. Thank you.

I am using below data

```
var data1 = [{
    Completion_Status: "Completed",
    End_Date: "12/16/2019",
    ID: 10002,
    Availability: "No",
    Received: "12-09-2019",
    Manufacture: "7-21-2013",
}, {
    Completion_Status: "in progress",
    End_Date: "11/15/2018",
    ID: 10002,
    Availability: "No",
    Received: "12-09-2019",
    Manufacture: "7-21-2013",
}, {
    Completion_Status: "not started",
   End_Date: "01/02/2021",
    ID: 10002,
    Availability: "No",
    Received: "12-09-2019",
    Manufacture: "7-21-2013",
},
{
Completion_Status: "Completed",
    End_Date: "12/16/2019",
    ID: 10002,
    Availability: "No",
    Received: "12-09-2019",
    Manufacture: "7-21-2013",
},
{
    Completion_Status: "Completed",
    End_Date: "08/19/2019",
    ID: 10002,
    Availability: "No",
    Received: "12-09-2019",
    Manufacture: "7-21-2013",
}, {
    Completion_Status: "in progress",
    End_Date: "07/19/2020",
    ID: 10002,
    Availability: "No",
    Received: "12-09-2019",
    Manufacture: "7-21-2013",
},
{
    Completion_Status: "Completed",
    End_Date: "08/19/2019",
    ID: 10002,
    Availability: "No",
    Received: "12-09-2019",
    Manufacture: "7-21-2013",
},{
    Completion_Status: "not started",
    End_Date: "03/14/1990",
    ID: 10002,
    Availability: "No",
    Received: "12-09-2019",
    Manufacture: "7-21-2013",
},
{
Completion_Status: "Completed",
    End_Date: "12/16/2019",
    ID: 10002,
    Availability: "No",
    Received: "12-09-2019",
    Manufacture: "7-21-2013",
},
{
    Completion_Status: "Completed",
   End_Date: "05/16/2020",
    ID: 10002,
    Availability: "No",
    Received: "12-09-2019",
    Manufacture: "7-21-2013",
},
{
    Completion_Status: "Completed",
   End_Date: "05/16/2020",
    ID: 10002,
    Availability: "No",
    Received: "12-09-2019",
    Manufacture: "7-21-2013",
},{
    Completion_Status: "in progress",
   End_Date: "01/06/1900",
    ID: 10002,
    Availability: "No",
    Received: "12-09-2019",
    Manufacture: "7-21-2013",
}, {
    Completion_Status: "not started",
    End_Date: "05/31/2020",
    ID: 10002,
    Availability: "No",
    Received: "12-09-2019",
    Manufacture: "7-21-2013",
},
{
    Completion_Status: "Completed",
   End_Date: "05/16/2020",
    ID: 10002,
    Availability: "No",
    Received: "12-09-2019",
    Manufacture: "7-21-2013",
},
{
    Completion_Status: "Completed",
   End_Date: "05/16/2020",
    ID: 10002,
    Availability: "No",
    Received: "12-09-2019",
    Manufacture: "7-21-2013",
},
];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the [boost.seriesThreshold](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/boost.seriesThreshold) to boost series, below example how to add boost in area chart.

```
let data1 = [],
  data2 = []

for (let i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
  data1.push(Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10))
  data2.push(Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10))

}
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    type: 'area',
    zoomType: 'x'
  },
  boost: {
    seriesThreshold: 10
  },

  plotOptions: {
    area: {
      stacking: 'normal'
    }
  },
  series: [{
    data: data1
  }, {
    data: data2
  }]
});
```

Article How to add boost module with description how it works:
[boost-module#series-boosting-versus-chart-boosting](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/advanced-chart-features/boost-module#series-boosting-versus-chart-boosting)

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/jb96ye58/1/

API references:
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/boost, https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/boost.seriesThreshold,

Comment: Thank you for your help. can you please help me on how can I map these dates on x-axis based on completion status count on particular date.

Comment: Try to [parsed](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/data.parsed) your data, [working-with-data](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/working-with-data/data-intro#working-with-data).